# cannot convert from 'ListMapColor.MyContainer' to 'System.Drawing.Color'

Tags: c#, colors, hashset

Im tryin to add a list with Hashset.

what im tryin to do? Im Tryin to mapping Haset Color some piece of image

Why ? Because i wanna to Compare Hashset list Colors in Real time and i need my own libary to gain process fast in real time for compare image's

Did u Research on Internet? Yes, but I didnt find something about usin hashset colors with ADD.

I did example to someone can help please.

```
public class ListMapColor
{


    public class MyContainer
    {
        public Color Number { get; set; }
        public Color Name { get; set; }
        public MyContainer(Color number, Color name)
        {
            Number = number;
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public HashSet<Color> Battle(HashSet<Color> colors)
    {

        return colors.Add( new MyContainer (Color.FromArgb(255, 47, 47, 47), Color.FromName("ff2f2f2f") );

    }


}
```

Comment: You are trying to add a MyContainer object to a hashet of Color objects. Use `HashSet<MyContainer>` instead.

Comment: thx, but there is nother error 
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<System.Drawing.Color>'

Comment: Yeah, need to see your code changes. Seems your hashset is still HashSet<Color>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original code posted you have a type error, which is exactly what the exception is telling you. It's expecting a Color object and you are giving it a MyContainer object and there is no way to convert between the two.

My comment suggested changing your code to the following:

```
public class ListMapColor
{


   public class MyContainer
   {
       public Color Number { get; set; }
       public Color Name { get; set; }
       public MyContainer(Color number, Color name)
       {
           Number = number;
           Name = name;
       }
   }

   public HashSet<MyContainer> Battle(HashSet<MyContainer> colors)
   {

       return colors.Add( new MyContainer (Color.FromArgb(255, 47, 47, 47), Color.FromName("ff2f2f2f") );

   }


}
```

That will fix the type Error. If you want a HashSet of Color objects you need to be adding Color objects, not MyContainer objects.

I'm not sure why you'd want to do that though.

Seems you may want something along the lines of:

```
    HashSet<Color> myColors = new HashSet<Color>();

    myColors.Add(Color.FromArgb(255,47,47,47));
    myColors.Add(Color.FromName("ff2f2f2f"));
    myColors.Add(Color.FromName("AliceBlue"));
```

Then you can access all the Color methods you may need:

```
    foreach(Color color in myColors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(color.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(color.IsKnownColor);
        Console.WriteLine(color.ToArgb());
        Console.WriteLine(color.IsNamedColor());
    }
```

Comment: Glad to help. Best of luck.